# Consuming and parsing Spring Boot HATEOAS API's nested response in Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, loops, response, spring-hateoas

I have the following response JSON that I'm receiving from my back-end API:

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "vehicleListingList": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "modelYear": "2022",
                "make": "Honda",
                "model": "Civic",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/listings/1"
                    },
                    "vehicleListings": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/listings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "modelYear": "2017",
                "make": "Honda",
                "model": "CR-V",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/listings/2"
                    },
                    "vehicleListings": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/listings"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/listings"
        }
    }
}
```

How do I drill down to the vehicle listing list and parse the data for my AppComponent HTML template?

*app.component.ts*

```
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { VehicleListing } from './vehicle-listing';
import { VehicleListingService } from './vehicle-listing.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public responseObj: VehicleListing[];

  constructor(private listingService: VehicleListingService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getListings();
  }

  public getListings(): void {
    this.listingService.getListings().subscribe(
      (response: VehicleListing[]) => {
        this.responseObj = response;
        console.log(this.responseObj);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using **ngFor* to loop through the response but the first level of the response is not really iterating, or at least I don't need to through it, I just need the listing list,so that's probably not my solution I later realized, at least not yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is an object and you can use `ngFor` over an array only not on object so you want to loop over `response._embedded.vehicleListingList` instead of response itself.So change your getListings method to

```
public getListings(): void {
    this.listingService.getListings().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        this.responseObj = response._embedded?.vehicleListingList;//here you need vehicleListingList not the whole response
        console.log(this.responseObj);
      },
      (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        alert(error.message);
      }
    );
  }
```

Then on UI you can do something like

```
<ng-container *ngIf="responseObj">
<div *ngFor="let item of responseObj">{{item.modelYear}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I get the error `Property '_embedded' does not exist on type 'VehicleListing[]'.ts(2339)` under *_embedded* on the line of the new code change. Do I possibly need to define it somehow in the VehicleListing interface?

Comment: what you get when you do `console.log(response);`

Comment: I actually solved it by changing the function return type to `any` in my service class. I'm not sure if this is best practice though. Your `getListings()` implementation worked though so thanks for that.